# Regex to match between certain xml tags

Tags: regex

Consider the following string

```
<Document>
<name>title</name>
<visibility>1</visibility>
<Style id="KMLStyler">
<IconStyle>

<Placemark id="kml_2">
<name>kml_2</name>
<snippet> </snippet>
<description>
.....
<Placemark id="kml_4">
<name>kml_4</name>
<snippet> </snippet>
<description><![CDATA[<center><table><tr><th colspan='2' align='center'><em>Attributes</em></th></tr>
```

I want to match everything between `<name><\name>` except if it is not followed by the tag `<snippet>`

I have this regular expression:
`<name>[\s\S]*?<\/name>[\r\n]<snippet> <\/snippet>`

It almost works, but it also matches the first `<name>` tag: `<name>title</name>` which is not followed by `<snippet>`.

How can I make a regex that only matches all the other name tags?

Comment: Someone will link to this, so it might just as well be me ;) https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2064981

Comment: Change `[\s\S]` to `[^\n]` might enough. Further improvement to `(?<=<name>)[^\n]*?(?=<\/name>[\r\n]<snippet> <\/snippet>)`, so only the content matched.

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: I am using this with Python within FME. The solution from @Eraklon works well. Thank you @Eraklon!

Comment: Oh okay, good luck. The right way to do it is with XPath but if your data has little variance or surprises then regex can work.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```php
<name>(?:(?!<name>)[\s\S])*?<\/name>[\r\n]<snippet> <\/snippet>
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/GkcJYS/1).

**Explanation**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  <name>                   '<name>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      <name>                   '<name>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\s\S]                   any character of: whitespace (\n, \r,
                             \t, \f, and " "), non-whitespace (all
                             but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*?                      end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  <                        '<'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  name>                    'name>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [\r\n]                   any character of: '\r' (carriage return),
                           '\n' (newline)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  <snippet> <              '<snippet> <'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  snippet>                 'snippet>'
```